# How do I install an old version of SDL (1.2) for development?

Tags: software-installation, sdl

I'm working on a project for which I will have to use SDL. I installed it as described [here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Installation), but when I tried to `cmake` the project I needed it for, I ran into problems. I found out that cmake does not work with SDL 2.0, but it does with SDL 1.2. Apparently there are some workarounds though, such as [this](https://github.com/brendan-w/collector/blob/master/cmake/FindSDL2.cmake) - but honestly, I have really no idea what to do with this...

So I'm trying to just install SDL 1.2. I tried to follow these instructions:

1. Get a copy of the source code, either from Mercurial or an official tarball or whatever.
2. Make a separate build directory (SDL will refuse to build in the base of the source tree).
3. Run the configure script to set things up.
4. Run `make` to compile SDL. Run "make install" to install your new SDL build on the system.

I did manage to hg clone the old version, but trying to make it, this is not possible. The readme tells me to run `autogen.sh`, but this "cannot find autoconf".

Further googling suggests I might need the development version, but now I'm really lost on where to get it from and how to install it.
I'd really appreciate any help with this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All currently supported versions of Ubuntu have SDL 1.2 packages in their official repositories. Try installing `libsdl1.2-dev`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but I get a problem I had earlier as well: apparently there are a  some unresolved dependencies (`libsdl1.2debian` and `libpulse-dev`). I tried installing these beforehand, but of course they also have a number of dependencies, and so on... I found a source online that said I'd have to install `build-essential xorg-dev libudev-dev libts-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libasound2-dev libpulse-dev libopenal-dev libogg-dev libvorbis-dev libaudiofile-dev libpng12-dev libfreetype6-dev libusb-dev libdbus-1-dev zlib1g-dev libdirectfb-dev`, but that led to the same problem.

Comment: It looks like your repositories are in an inconsistent state, you may want to ask another question about that.

Comment: Initially I also got issues .. cause I tried install the debian package .. I then removed it `sudo apt remove sdl-devel` and install again `apt install libsdl1.2-dev` , it was correctly installed.